# I have a power bi desktop connected with sql database and have some reports in it

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I have a power bi desktop connected with SQL database and have some reports in it.
Now I want to generate following things

1. Every time user enter the name of the database my reports gets automatically refresh and exported in PDF or excel.
2. If possible I have browser where user can enter the SQL database name and UI pop up and end user can see the power BI dashboard where all reports automatically refreshed as per the user input SQL database name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For ask 1:

> Refer [Create and use R visuals in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/service-r-visuals) Once R is installed, open the Run R Script and paste the below R script, depending on your destination and save it.

```
   Example as a excel file:  write.xlsx(dataset, file = "C:/dataset.xlsx")
```

> If you are interested in (PDF) and know Microsoft Power Platform, use ****On Power BI button clicked**** trigger followed with [Export To File for Power BI Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerbi/#export-to-file-for-power-bi-reports) actions API to export a PDF to your local directory. [Demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJAoF.png)

For ask 2:

> You can check [Embed a report in a secure portal or website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20embed%20Power%20BI%20reports%20into,page%20navigation%20and%20filter%20setting.%20Only...%20See%20More.) to easily embed reports in internal web portals and utilize [Automatic page refresh in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh#automatic-page-refresh-in-the-power-bi-service) to set automatic page refresh for reports as long as the data source is **DirectQuery**.

Power BI Desktop has no restrictions for refresh intervals and can be as frequent as every second. But when reports are published to the Power BI service, certain restrictions apply.

Alternately you can use [Datasets Power BI REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdataset) - to trigger a refresh for the specified dataset from "My Workspace".

POST [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D/refreshes)

You can also leverage [Q&A for Power BI business users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-q-and-a) the fastest way to get an answer from your data by asking a question using natural language.